# Is there any way to extend Commerce Scale Unit customer and consumer APIs for Microsoft D365 Commerce?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Just now I have started learning Microsoft Dynamics 365 Commerce.
I have found an article that depicts the existing APIs.
[Commerce Scale Unit customer and consumer APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/dev-itpro/retail-server-customer-consumer-api)

Please correct me if I am wrong, **Is there any way to extend these APIs to add some custom business logic?**

I have gone through the docs provided by Microsoft but it is not mentioned anywhere how to extend the consumer APIs.

I have prefered this link [Create a Retail Server extension API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/dev-itpro/retail-server-icontroller-extension) to create a new API but how to extend the existing one is not mentioned.

Any suggestion/response would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out that We can extend the API to add our business logic by using the Triggers corresponding to the request.

Along with the triggers, there are request handlers that we can use to implement the custom business logic corresponding to a request.

- [Post Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/dev-itpro/commerce-runtime-extensibility-trigger)
- [CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/dev-itpro/commerce-runtime-extensibility)
- [CRT Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/dev-itpro/commerce-runtime-extensibility#scenario)